# Invisible focused item using Ctrl+Arrow Key in Nautilus

Tags: 16.04, keyboard, nautilus, shortcut-keys, 16.10

When we want only use the keyboard on Nautilus and we want to select non-consecutive files and folders, we cannot see that files has the focus.
Holding down the Ctrl key, we can moving through the files and folder with the Arrows key,  but only when we hit Space key, we realize where we are.
This becomes a bigger problem when there are many files and folders and we have to hitting the arrow key very quickly.
This problem happen in Ambiance Theme, **only in High Contrast Theme it works well.**

---

*In High Contrast Theme you can see that Template folder has the focus*
[image]

---

*It is in Ambiance Theme(default), the Template folder has the focus, nevertheless  it is impossible to know.*
[image]

Comment: What is the ctrl key going to add vs. just using the arrow keys which work fine?

Comment: In the case you want to select _multiple **non consecutive** files_, Ctrl+space (for select the file) then Arrow keys for move the focus to the next file, and select (Ctrl+space). Greetings from Ecuador.

Comment: Could you edit the post so the pictures are embedded as images? I am using a mobile phone now so it's a bit hard to fix it myself.

Comment: I have not reputation for do that. Laugh

Comment: I have to say that the problem persist on Ubuntu 16.10 Yakkety Yak

Comment: Post edited @andrea

Answer (score 1):

I could fix that thanks to Bruno Santos.
You might to add a dashed line decoration for the Ambience Theme, to.

> /usr/share/themes/Ambiance/gtk-3.0/apps/nautilus.css
>
> ---
>
> ```
> NautilusWindow * {
>     -GtkPaned-handle-size: 1;
>     outline-color: @selected_bg_color;
>     outline-style: dashed;
>     outline-width: 1px;
>     outline-radius: 4px;
>     outline-offset: -1px;
> }
> ```

More about this Bug [here.](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/light-themes/+bug/1441296)

Comment: works here too though because I use custom selected_bg_color & selected_fg_color in ambiance went with the later as it's darker (#3c3b37

Comment: How can we modified that portion of code for to display only a orange line below the file or folder that has the focus?. the same way that [Dolphin](http://imgur.com/DLzuVbF) file manager.

Comment: I forgotten to mention your username @doug